# Creating a Pattern with Asterisks

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a pattern made with asterisks by using for, if, and while loop.

For example, If I put 1 to the variable h, it would show like this.

.

2 to the variable h

.

.

..

3 to the variable h

.

.

..

.

..

...

4 to the variable h

.

.

..

.

..

...

.

..

...

....

5 to the variable h

.

.

..

.

..

...

.

..

...

....

.

..

...

....

.....

Basically, if I put 5 to the variable h, it is repeating itself from 1 to 4 and creating a right triangle with 5 layers of asterisks.

The R code that I have written were

```
cat("enter an integer:")
h <- scan(n=1)
for(i in 1:h){
 for(j in 1:h){
  if(i >= j)
    cat("*")
  }
  cat("\n")
}
```

I know how to get the first one which is putting 1 to the variable h but, I could not figure out for the rest of them.

I will really appreciate your help!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to acheive here, but you might think about generate a small function that creates your asterisk right triange for any value `n`

```
rt_triangle_n <- \(n) {
  for(i in 1:n) cat(paste0(rep("*", i), collapse=""), "\n")
}
```

You can then use that function, say in a for loop from 1 to 5:

```
for(i in 1:5) cat("\n", rt_triangle_n(i))
```

Output:

```
* 

* 
** 

* 
** 
*** 

* 
** 
*** 
**** 

* 
** 
*** 
**** 
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put another loop outside the inner.

```
h <- 4
for(i in seq_len(h)) {
  for(j in seq_len(i)) {
    writeLines(strrep("*", j))
  }
}
*
*
**
*
**
***
*
**
***
****
```