# Asterisk Triangle Patterns

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a triangle patterns consisting of asterisks by only using for, if and while loop.

If I put 1 to the variable h, it would appear like this.

```
*
```

2 to the variable h

```
*
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

3 to the variable h

```
*
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

4 to the variable

```
*
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

```
* * * *
```

and 5 to the variable h

```
*
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

```
* * * *
```

```
*
```

```
* *
```

```
* * *
```

```
* * * *
```

```
* * * * *
```

Basically, if I put 5 to the variable, it repeats the previous patterns that were inputted to the variable by 1,2,3,4 and a pattern that were inputted to the variable by 5 and printed in one pattern.

The R code that I have written were

```
cat("enter an integer:")
h <- scan(n=1)
for(i in 1:h){
for(j in 1:h){
  for(k in 1:h){
  if(i >= k)
    cat("*")
  }
  cat("\n")
  }
}
```

If I put 5 to the variable h, it would appear like this.

```
*
*
*
*
*
**
**
**
**
**
***
***
***
***
***
****
****
****
****
****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

I just could not figure out how to do it, so I would be really grateful if you solve this problem.

Comment: This is a great case for recursion

Comment: Weirdly enough, this was asked 2 days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928492/creating-a-pattern-with-asterisks)

Answer (score 2):

```
h <- as.integer(readline(prompt = "enter an integer: "))

for(s in 1:h) {
  for(i in 1:s) {
    cat(paste(rep("*", i), collapse = ""), "\n")
  }
}

# R: h <- as.integer(readline(prompt = "enter an integer: "))
# enter an integer: 5

#   * 
#   * 
#   ** 
#   * 
#   ** 
#   *** 
#   * 
#   ** 
#   *** 
#   **** 
#   * 
#   ** 
#   *** 
#   **** 
#   *****
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the next code snippet:

```
cat("Enter an integer:")
h <- scan(n=1)

# create an empty list to store the patterns
pattern_list <- list()

for (i in 1:h) {
  # create an empty list to store the lines of the current pattern
  pattern <- list()
  
  # first loop to generate the current pattern
  for (j in 1:i) {
    line <- rep("*", j)
    pattern[[j]] <- paste(line, collapse=" ")
  }
  
  # second loop to repeat previous patterns
  for (p in 1:(i-1)) {
    if (j <= length(pattern_list)) {
        prev_pattern <- pattern_list[[p]]
        for (k in 1:length(prev_pattern)) {
          pattern[[p+k]] <- prev_pattern[[k]]
        }
    }
  }
  
  # store the current pattern in a list for future use
  pattern_list[[i]] <- pattern
  
  # print the current pattern
  for (j in 1:length(pattern)) {
    cat(pattern[[j]], "\n")
  }
}
```

and the output for, for example, `h = 4` will be:

```
* 
* 
* * 
* 
* * 
* * * 
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * *
```

Comment: Your code does not work.

Comment: @songie, updated the second loop. Now it works fine, at least for me